# How to fetch PostgreSQL binaries with checksums (for windows)

Tags: windows, postgresql, checksum

I need the PostgreSQL binaries for windows as a .zip, which I can only find on the enterpriseDB website, but there are no checksums available.
EnterpriseDB support wasn't helpuful because I have no support contract.

Are there any other sources for this download, which I'm not aware off?